# Can't run my application on my Nexus 4 (unauthorized phone)

Tags: android, eclipse, rsa, adb

I was doing the Android tutorial on the Google website and I was at the point where you want to run your fantastic Hello World application on your phone. When I run my application from Eclipse, I see that my phone status is ?? and the target is unknown. When running adb devices in cmd, it says that my phone is unauthorized. It appears that it has something to do with the RSA fingerprint prompt. I don't remember ever getting such a prompt. Yes, I am running in PTP mode and debugging is enabled. I tried, after looking around on internet for multiple hours:

-Enabling/disabling debugging mode repeatedly
-Uninstalling and reinstalling my drivers for my phone or ADB
-adb-killserver and adb-startserver
-Restarting my phone and unplugging/replugging in multiple ways

I did notice that in my (user)/.android/ folder, I don't have a file called adbkey.pub (which is apparently the file that's supposed to have my key). Anyway, I don't think I've ever received the prompt about RSA fingerprint and I can't make it appear in any way.

Do you guys have any idea what I could do at this point. I tried about everything on these forums and around on the Internet but maybe there is something else I could do. Should I reset my phone to factory settings at this point to make the prompt appear again?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your android SDK is up to date (I think we're on v22.xx of the tools). Older versions fail in the manner you describe when hooked up to Android 4.2+ devices.

Comment: My SDK is up to date (it says 22.2.1). I even tried the Eclipse + downloading SDK separately instead of the ADT bundle from the Google website and it doesn't work either. I really don't know what to do at this point. Do I really need to root and go somewhere on my devices files to delete the key?

Comment: Hmm, Any chance there's an old version of the SDK tools taking presidence over the v22s? Happened to me once, drove me crazy. Try 'adb version'. If that's not it, my last recourse would be a factory reset. That's about all I can think of, don't know how the key validation works.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have MTP transfer mode on?  I just had this problem, solved by restarting the adb server and then disabled MTP on the phone at which point it immediately prompted for the RSA fingerprint and connected.